# how to determine the number of users that can be supported by my server for a specific app

Tags: java, gwt

I am creating a Java web app that is meant for use by Facebook users.

The web app is planned to be hosted on Amazon EC2- now I want to find out how many users can be supported by one server. So that I have a better idea of the costs involved.

Can you tell me how to determine this, for a java + gwt web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since programming products are complicated and contain many layers theoretical estimation of application performance is hard and even probably impossible. Each layer can be a bottle neck and it is hard to expect which one.

So, the only way is to perform experimental bench-marking you your specific application deployed on specific environment.

There are a lot of tolls both commercial and free. I'd start from some kind of benchmarking with JMeter. It is open source, easily extendable and very popular product for performance testing.